# Python pymarc - how to print field tag and each indicator and subfield

Tags: python, python-3.x, marc

I have a MARC21 record in an input file. 
I am trying to print it in Aleph Sequential format.

How?
I want to print record number (9 digits), space, the field tag, **indicators**, space, the L letter, space and then each subfield tag and subfield contests.

I am trying to use the record.get_fields(), but I do not succeed in getting the field indicators and subfield tag.

**How cat I get and print field indicators? 
How do I print ech subfield tag and then each subfield value?**

Here is my code:

```
from pymarc import MARCReader
from pymarc import Record, Field 

with open('machiavellism_biu_2018.mrc', 'rb') as fh:
    reader = MARCReader(fh, to_unicode=True) 
    # loop 1
    recnum = 0
    for record in reader: 
        # loop 2
        recnum += 1
        for tield_contents in record.get_fields():
            print ('%09d' % recnum,' ',tield_contents.tag,'  ',' L',tield_contents.value())
        ## end loop 2
```

An example for the output:

```
python pymarc_000002.py
```

...

```
000000001   001     L 002547390
000000001   003     L OCoLC
000000001   005     L 20181016125657.0
000000001   008     L 180214t20182018enka     b    001 0 eng
000000001   092     L 302 BER m
000000001   020     L 9781138093317
000000001   035     L (OCoLC)991673448
000000001   040     L eng rda
000000001   041     L eng
000000001   100     L Bereczkei, Tamás lat author
000000001   245     L Machiavellianism : the psychology of manipulation / Tamas Bereczkei.
000000001   264     L London : Routledge, 2018.
000000001   264     L ©2018
```

Answer (score 0):

If the marc field has a first or second indicator, then it will be parsed into `.indicator1` or `.indicator2` attributes.  They will be both be defined even if only one is defined in the marc record, so something like this should work.

```
if hasattr(field_contents, 'indicator1'):
       indicator1 = field_contents.indicator1
       indicator2 = field_contents.indicator2
```